# AngularJS Dynamic Slider Control

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, slider

I am working on a project that requires a slider control that corresponds to an image and or a multitude of div objects. The spacing of the slider is irregular (the steps could be [1,4,7,13,14,16...]). Also the steps will correspond to specific spots on an image and or to a specific div object. The perfect slider would be dynamic and re-size with the screen but that may be actually impossible.

The hard part is that I am unable to use JQueryUI, instead I am limited to using controls that work with AngularJS.

I have been looking for hours and cannot find anything that would be a good starting point. So my question is whether anyone has found a good slider control to use with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

This one fits some of your criteria
[angularjs-slider](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider)